# Application crashes when requesting CLLocation property from appDelegate

Tags: ios, cllocation

I have an application which creates a class instance that contains (amongst other things) some location data.

In the app delegate I set up location services and start grabbing the location data;

```
//Delegate method to receive location information from locationManager
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

    latestLocation = newLocation;//Make latest location the same as NewLocation
    NSLog(@"Location is: %@", latestLocation);
}
```

I declare latest location as a property so that I can get at the CLLocation instance from another class.

My captures class, when called grabs the CLLocation when its init method is called;

```
//Designated initialiser
-(id) initWithVideoPath:(NSString *) vPath 
              userNotes:(NSString *) uNotes
         retentionState:(NSString *) rState

{
    //Call the super classes designated initializer
    [super init];

    //Get a pointer to the application delegate so we can access the location props
    Rolling_VideoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (Rolling_VideoAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;


    //If superclass failed to init
    if (!self)
        return nil;


    //Give the variables some initial values
    [self setVideoPath:vPath];
    [self setUserNotes:uNotes];
    [self setRetentionState:rState];
    dateCreated = [[NSDate alloc] init];


    mp = [[MapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:[[appDelegate latestLocation]coordinate]];//get the location from the coords from appDelegate

    return self;

    [dateCreated release];
}
```

However the app crashes when the mapPoint init is called. The problem is I'm not getting the CLLocation information in properly.

Comment: I think that the `latestLocation` ivar is not yet initialized when you first start the LocationManager. In your `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, initialize it like this: `latestLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:0.0f longitude:0.0f];`. Do not forget to release it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still unsure why the original solution does not work, so if anyone has any insights please do enlighten.

I have however worked out a slightly inelegant work around using NSUserDefaults

```
    latestLocation = newLocation;//Make latest location the same as NewLocation

    //Use NSUser Defaults to save the CLLocation instance
    NSUserDefaults *location = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [location setDouble:latestLocation.coordinate.latitude forKey:@"lat"];
    [location setDouble:latestLocation.coordinate.longitude forKey:@"longd"];
```

I needed to break out the lat and long as NSUserDefaults will not store CLLocation objects (NSCoding compatability), the reconstruct them in the captures class;

```
    NSUserDefaults *location = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];//Get a handle to the user defaults
    CLLocationDegrees lat = [location doubleForKey:@"lat"];
    CLLocationDegrees longd = [location doubleForKey:@"longd"];
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat longitude:longd];

    mp = [[MapPoint alloc]initWithCoordinate:[currentLocation coordinate]];//get the location from the coords from appDelegate
```

Comment: In didUpdateToLocation, when setting it, try using `self.latestLocation = newLocation;` to retain the value.

Comment: YES! Retention was the problem. A simple retain increment solved the issue.